# Using same form on multiple pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I am writing an application, and I have a user form, which will be the same for the users and the administrators on different pages.

I want to only create the form once, and then be able to put it on two different aspx files.

I tried it with the "control", but it then gets really complicated trying to access fields on the control from the aspx page to do the calculation, etc.

is there another way to do this? creating a form in one place, be able to add it to any aspx page, and have easy access to it's controls?

Comment: Define "really complicated" in regards to accessing the controls. this.myUserControl.FindControl() or set the accessor to public works. Also, ideally, if the logic applies to the form shouldn't it be in the user control, then exposed via public properties/methods?

Answer (score 3):

It's not very difficult at all. You can provide an accessor method or make the control inside public.

Example: A page which displays the contents of a `TextBox` inside a control, when a button is pressed.
Control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Page

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <Test:Control ID="ctlTest" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

Code (If TextBox1 is public)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = ctlTest.TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Or you could have, in the code of the control

```
public string GetText()
{
    return TextBox1.Text;
}
```

And in the aspx code page

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = ctlTest.GetText();
}
```

What is so difficult about that?!

Comment: In my experience this is the correct approach to encapsulating page elements and associated code for reuse.  You just have to expose properties for the information you want to make available to the containing page.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create MasterPage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

so that you can share common controls between pages. Master pages can be nested, too. You can access controls on master page from child page via Master.FindControl("abc")

EDIT: it seems that you want to reuse common piece of functionality, then you might want to use user control, like in this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3457w616.aspx

Comment: I already have a master page... for like my logos and menus... are you saying i should create a new master page just for a user form?

Comment: what should containt that user form? one page can have only one MasterPage howerver master pages can be nested, so you would create master page with logos and menus and then second one with that form - like a template. But if you want just new control, then you can use UserControl which can have its own public propeties

Answer (score 0):

you created the control, and do not use findControl() method to access the control that inside you UserControl, that is not feasible or proper solution.

Better to use Properies. Define Properties, so your control can be generalised and you can use that on multiple pages.